# How to get "number" of day

Tags: c#, date, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I would like to get the "number of the day. For example:
January the first would be 1.
Febuary the first would be the 32.

So that we get up a whole year with 365 days.

Sry for my bad english :)

Comment: What about `DateTime.DayOfYear` property. Do you have "string" or DateTime object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`DateTime.DayOfYear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear.aspx) is what you want

```
 DateTime.Now.DayOfYear
```

or whatever yourDate is;

```
yourDate.DayOfYear;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `DayOfYear` property of any `DateTime` object:

```
var date = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
var dayNumber = date.DayOfYear;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a `DateTime` property named: [DayOfYear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear.aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.DayOfYear);
```

Or for any date:

```
var d = new DateTime(2012, 8, 30);
Console.WriteLine(d.DayOfYear);
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
private int GetDaysInAYear(int year)
{

   int days = 0;
   for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
   {
       days += DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, i);
   }
  return days;
}
```

and do this (method above to get the number of days in year)

DateTime.Now.DayOfYear

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.DayOfYear.ToString()
```